# How to fix keyboard error in react navigation?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a screen with input component

If this screen is configured as a first screen through initialRouteName everything works fine. But when i navigate to this screen from another screen, on clicking the input field the keyboard goes down after a second. This happens for all screens except initialRoute.

Im using react-navigation's createStackNavigator

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = "Membership ID"
    autoCapitalize = "characters"
    style = {styles.textInputStyle}
    value = {this.state.mId}
    onChangeText = {this.handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

Actually it is ViewPagerAndroid causing this.

Just made

```
autoPlay =false
```